# Doubt in STL priority_queue instantiation

Tags: c++

In the code base I'm maintaining, I find the following instantiation of a STL `priority_queue`.
I didn't understand the `pq(order)` part. What could be `order` there in the context of `priority_queue` instantiation?

```
priority_queue<Record*, vector<Record*>, Comparator > pq(order);
```

EDIT: Could `order` be the argument to the `Comparator` constructor? In fact, order is not an instance of type `Comparator`. `Comparator` class has a constructor that takes argument of the type of `order`. 
But I don't see how it fits in the syntax.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/priority_queue/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, the code is using the following constructor of `priority_queue`:

```
explicit priority_queue ( const Compare& x = Compare(), const Container& y = Container());
```

If so, then `order` is an instance of type `Comparator`.

If it has been constructed with the default constructor, then you could just leave it out and call

```
priority_queue<Record*, vector<Record*>, Comparator > pq;
```

Comment: Could `order` be the argument to the `Comparator` constructor? In fact, order is not an instance of type `Comparator`. `Comparator` class has a constructor that takes argument of the type of `order`.

Comment: Yes, that would work assuming that your `Comparator`-from-typeof-order constructor is non-explicit. In this case the compiler is inferring the construction of a `Comparator` from `order` to make the correct type for the `priority_queue` constructor, i.e. it's actually compiling `pq( Comparator(order) )`.

Comment: If `Comparator` has an implicit converting constructor from `order` then yes that would work.

Comment: Is there any reference that could give this interpretation of the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that's a variable instantiation of `pq`, of type `priority_queue<Record*, vector<Record*>, Comparator >`, then `order` is the constructor argument. In this case it's using the [explicit constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/priority_queue/):

```
 explicit priority_queue ( const Compare& x = Compare(),
                           const Container& y = Container() );
```

and so `order` will be an existing object of the Compare template parameter case - `Comparator` in your case - that is used for ordering.

Comment: Didn't get that. ctor of  what?

Answer (score 1):

`order` is an instance of the `Comparator` class. It defines the comparison mechanism of the priority queue, to determine which element will be at the top.

Take a look at the [`std::priority_queue` reference](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/priority_queue/start), and the [constructor signature in particular](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/priority_queue/constructor).

Answer (score 1):

`order` is the argument to the constructor of the `priority_queue<Record*, vector<Record*>, Comparator>` instance named `pq`.  If you look at the [documentation for the constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/priority_queue/priority_queue/) you'll see that `order` is the `Comparator` instance used in the instance.